# How to restart activity within TabActivity

Tags: android

In my app I have used the following code to close and restart my current activity. But my problem is, I have used 3 tab activity as nested. total 9 activities. so while using the following code my app loading too slow. I think there is a smarter way than this. If anyone knows please suggest me friends.

```
LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
String currentTag = tab.getCurrentTabTag();             
Class<? extends Activity> currentClass = manager.getCurrentActivity().getClass();
manager.removeAllActivities();
manager.startActivity(currentTag, new Intent(MainActivity.this,currentClass));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INTENT.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

This command simply restarts all activity without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the "smarter" way here would be do not use deprecated class `TabActivity` and for sure do not nest several `TabHost`. You probably should use `Fragments` and at least something like [FragmentTabHost](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html).